# Google Drive PHP API - Simple File Upload

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to write a small script to upload a local file to Google Drive, using Google Drive PHP API. The documentation is very poor maintained, but so far I am pretty sure the code should be looking like that:

```
<?php

include_once 'Google/Client.php';
include_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
include_once 'Google/Auth/OAuth2.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
$client->setClientId('dfgdfgdg');
$client->setClientSecret('dfgdfgdf');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');


$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$data = file_get_contents("a.jpg");

// create and upload a new Google Drive file, including the data
try
{
//Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);

$file->setTitle(uniqid().'.jpg');
$file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'media',
));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage();
}

print_r($createdFile);

?>
```

The issue is I am not able to do the authentication right (or I am doing something else wrong?). The error I received is:

```
HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(compress.zlib://https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: operation failed'
```

Followed by this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: createdFile in C:\wamp\www\GoogleAPI\index.php on line 39
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you provide a simple working script of uploading a file to Google Drive using Google Drive PHP API? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this code to authenticate and upload a test file. You need to set `<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>` (and also in console) to this document itself to authenticate.

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>');
$client->setClientSecret('<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>');
$client->setRedirectUri('<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $data = file_get_contents('a.jpg');

    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
          'data' => $data,
          'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
          'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

    print_r($createdFile);

} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think the script you provided is very close to the thing I need. In my previous version I have successfully managed to get the $_GET['code'] value. With your version of the script it is OK too. My URL is changed to:

http://localhost/googleApi/index.php?code=4/T1PUKqjURysd_pzhnu7sfG_SPXxc.YsHYHi9UwVyjz_MlCJoi2I5xqokAI

Which means the code is OK. Unfortunately, right after that I receive those errors:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument'' in C:\wamp\www\GoogleAPI\Google\IO\Stream.php on line 112

Comment: some configuration in your server may fix the problem, I searched your error in OS and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25193378/3477084

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I can confirm the script is working! Another question -> I was asked do I accept the script to interact with the application. Can I make this authorization automatic in future? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, I followed one of your other answers and I have automated the process! Thank you!

Comment: @HafezDivandari How long code & access_token is valid after authentication?? And how can i use that in CRON Jobs because there we don't have manually allow from account

Comment: @NextgenAnak I've previously answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632241/3477084

Comment: Could someone please share complete code spec .

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<?php
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    //Request authorization
    print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
    print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for access token
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    $localfile = 'a.jpg';
    $title = basename($localfile);
    $file->setTitle($title);
    $file->setDescription('My File');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $data = file_get_contents($localfile);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
          'data' => $data,
          'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
        ));

    print_r($createdFile);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is old example, already deprecated from Google. Even the included files are changed.

Comment: Please send me latest api link

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run a PHP added in CRON. He asks for the verification code only the first time and then everything works. I've been running CRON for over 16h and everything is working perfectly.

Well, considering you've done the steps:

1. Create a Project on Google Cloud Platform;
2. In Credentials, you already have the OAuth 2.0 Client ID;
3. Downloaded credentials and renamed credentials.json;
4. Used composer to download Google Drive libraries;

References in:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

This code here is the "working" result of an upload to Google Drive in a specific subfolder. I hope it helps.

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');


    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
// Esse resultado é importante para ver que tudo está concetado;
// Esse comando deve exibir as ultimas 3 atividades do seu drive;
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 3,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
    }
}
//
// Fim atividades do Drive;
//


//Define variáveis de arquivos
//Aqui você pode substituir depois par algum array ou resultado do banco de dados
//Defina um bem simples inicialmente para ver que tudo funciona
$pasta      = 'substitua pela pasta';   // Um exemplo aqui é /home/usuario/public_html/arquivos_upload
$arquivo    = 'substitua pelo arquivo'; // arquivo.mp4
    printf("Pasta: %s || Arquivo: %s\n", $pasta, $arquivo);
}

//Essa é a pasta destino do Google Drive
$parentId   = 'substitua pelo ID da Pasta';


if ( !empty($arquivo) ) {

    //Define localização da pasta e arquivo
    $file_path = $pasta.'/'.$arquivo;

    //Conecta no Drive da sua conta
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    //Define nome do arquivo
    $file->setName($arquivo);

    //Define Diretório Destino lá no Google Drive
    $file->setParents(array($parentId));

    //Cria o arquivo no GDrive
    $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data'          => file_get_contents($file_path),
        'mimeType'      => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'resumable'
      )
    );

    // Grava Log do que foi feito UTC -3 horas;
    $DateTime = new DateTime();
    $DateTime->modify('-3 hours');
    $now = $DateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $logfile = $now.' Upload OK :: '.$arquivo.PHP_EOL;

    $myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $logfile, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

} else {

    //Grava Log
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $logfile .=$now.' =====SEM ARQUIVOS========'.PHP_EOL;

    $myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $logfile, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}

?>
```