# PHP Google Drive Simple Upload

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am new here and newbie in Google Drive thing. I managed to follow and install Google Drive v3.  Now, I am stuck as to how can I make a simple PHP code that will upload a text file to my Google Drive. I need a simple PHP code / guide on how to upload a small text file.  Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh I forgot to mention, the simple code needs to run on console using PHP-CLI.

Comment: I do not have an actual code yet but I saw some posts with codes.

Comment: `$client->setRedirectUri('<I DO NOT KNOW WHERE TO GET THIS>');` this is a url if after successful authenticate, and it should be available in your Google API Console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to upload file, then you can check the [DRIVE API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) documentaion for that.

Here you can find 3 options on how to upload file.

- [simple upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#simple)
- [multipart upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart)
- [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable)

Just visit the above link to know more about them.

**For the PHP code that you want**, then you can check the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload).
Just remember that you need to set `<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>` to the document to authenticate it.

For more information or other way to upload file using service account, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133141/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-using-service-account-in-php?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the process of file upload on google drive.
There is a repository on GitHub on how to authenticate and upload files on google drive using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) in PHP. You can give it a try. 
https://github.com/SM4991/php-google-drive

Comment: It is better if you can add more details here while posting the link because content in the link can be changed with the time