# Without using composer upload file to google driver using PHP?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

how to upload file to google drive without using composer in PHP.

Comment: ok, thats nice.

Comment: Check this before posting any questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i need upload file to google drive without using composer i saw so many questions all are using composer that the reason i posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive PHP API - Simple File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload)

Comment: I tried Google Drive PHP API -Simple File Upload method I got "Class 'Google_Service' not found " error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer reference see the website providing nice article http://mynixworld.info/2014/09/04/upload-file-google-drive-programmatically/