# A way to send files to Google Drive from Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-drive-api

How can I send files uploaded on my Wordpress page to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a authentication with the google drive api, and go from there.
This is not an easy thing to explain here.

The process of sending a file to drive is explained in this topic, although this is a plain php solution.

[Google Drive PHP API - Simple File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload)

You need to hook this into some WordPress action to actually send an upload to Drive.