# upload file to google drive and share link using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-drive-api

I want to write php code to upload files to google drive and share link. I need to integrate this to my website. so users can upload files to google drive and once they uploaded I can receive file link.

is this possible? are there any github sources to start? I am seeking help to get right start. please advice if anyone has done this before?

Comment: i think it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload#:~:text=jpg%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20create%20and,'.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write a PHP code to get the file link from data uploaded to Drive. If that is true, then you should explore the [Drive API PHP reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/). You can see an example code in the [Drive API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) and use it as a model.

To get the data from the uploaded file you can use [`get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and read the variables `webContentLink` and/or `webViewLink` (for the download link and the view link, respectively). Please, remember to use `*` on the request parameter `fields` to receive all the data. Don't hesitate to ask me further questions to help you better.